# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference RecyclerView Adapter Error

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, jsonparser

**Api (Interface)**

```
package com.example.openweathermap;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL="https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/";

    @GET("weather/")
    Call<WeatherResponse> getWeatherDetails(@Query("api_key")String api_key);


}
```

**My Model Class**

Here is my model class which consists of getters and setters

```
package com.example.openweathermap;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Weather {


    @SerializedName("coord")
    private String coord;
    @SerializedName("lon")
    private String lon;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    private String lat;

    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<Integer> weather = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("base")
    private String base;
    @SerializedName("main")
    private String main;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    private String temp;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    private String pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    private Integer humidity;
    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    private String temp_min;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    private String temp_max;

    @SerializedName("visibility")
    private String visibility;

    @SerializedName("wind")
    private String wind;
    @SerializedName("speed")
    private String speed;
    @SerializedName("deg")
    private String deg;

    @SerializedName("clouds")
    private String clouds;
    @SerializedName("all")
    private String all;

    @SerializedName("dt")
    private String dt;

    @SerializedName("sys")
    private String sys;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("country")
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    private String sunrise;
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    private String sunset;


    public Weather(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Weather(String coord, String lon, String lat, List<Integer> weather, String base, String main, String temp, String pressure, Integer humidity, String temp_min, String temp_max, String visibility, String wind, String speed, String deg, String clouds, String all, String dt, String sys, String type, String id, String message, String country, String sunrise, String sunset) {
        this.coord = coord;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.weather = weather;
        this.base = base;
        this.main = main;
        this.temp = temp;
        this.pressure = pressure;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.temp_min = temp_min;
        this.temp_max = temp_max;
        this.visibility = visibility;
        this.wind = wind;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.deg = deg;
        this.clouds = clouds;
        this.all = all;
        this.dt = dt;
        this.sys = sys;
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.country = country;
        this.sunrise = sunrise;
        this.sunset = sunset;
    }

    public String getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(String coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public List<Integer> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Integer> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public String getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(String pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    public Integer getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public String getTemp_min() {
        return temp_min;
    }

    public void setTemp_min(String temp_min) {
        this.temp_min = temp_min;
    }

    public String getTemp_max() {
        return temp_max;
    }

    public void setTemp_max(String temp_max) {
        this.temp_max = temp_max;
    }

    public String getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(String visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public String getWind() {
        return wind;
    }

    public void setWind(String wind) {
        this.wind = wind;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public String getDeg() {
        return deg;
    }

    public void setDeg(String deg) {
        this.deg = deg;
    }

    public String getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(String clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public String getAll() {
        return all;
    }

    public void setAll(String all) {
        this.all = all;
    }

    public String getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(String dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public String getSys() {
        return sys;
    }

    public void setSys(String sys) {
        this.sys = sys;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getSunrise() {
        return sunrise;
    }

    public void setSunrise(String sunrise) {
        this.sunrise = sunrise;
    }

    public String getSunset() {
        return sunset;
    }

    public void setSunset(String sunset) {
        this.sunset = sunset;
    }
}
```

**MyJSONResponse**
I am trying to get this data in adapter which is a RecyclerView Adapter

```
package com.example.openweathermap;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class WeatherResponse {
    @SerializedName("weather")
    private List<Weather> weather;
    @SerializedName("id")
    private  String id;
    @SerializedName("main")
    private  String main;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private  String description;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    private  String temp;

    public WeatherResponse(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public WeatherResponse(String weather, String id, String main, String description, String temp) {

        this.id = id;
        this.main = main;
        this.description = description;
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(String temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }
}

----------
**MyAdapter
```

This is the recyclerview adapter**

```
----------

package com.example.openweathermap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Weather> weathers;
    public Context context;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Weather> weathers, Context context) {
        this.weathers = weathers;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_items,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Weather  weather=weathers.get(position);
    holder.temp.setText(weather.getTemp());
    /*holder.name.setText(weather.getCountry());*/
    holder.description.setText(weather.getDescription());
    weathers=new ArrayList<>();


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return weathers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView temp;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;




        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            temp=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
            name=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            description=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);


        }
    }
}
```

---

Main Activity

---

```
package com.example.openweathermap;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Weather> weathersList;
    // TODO - insert your themoviedb.org API KEY here
    private final static String API_KEY = "ae47e0f7eb5fbbce0c9cfbdf1373a1b3";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        weathersList=new ArrayList<>();

        if (API_KEY.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please obtain your API KEY first ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
      getWeather();
    }

    private void getWeather() {
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api=retrofit.create(Api.class);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call=api.getWeatherDetails(API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Response<WeatherResponse> response) {

                ArrayList<Weather> weathersList = (ArrayList<Weather>) response.body().getWeather();
                adapter=new MyAdapter(weathersList,getApplicationContext());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<WeatherResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting an error as " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference RecyclerView Adapter Error" in MyAdapter

---

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @SebastienRieu he clearly knows what NPE is, he is trying to find the cause of it...